# Cypress Test Runner Reporter: NUnit?

Tags: junit, nunit, cypress

I am currently using **cypress test runner** with property [**--reporter junit**](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#Command-line-2), which generates test reporting results using [**JUnit XML Format**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.1.1/com.ibm.rsar.analysis.codereview.cobol.doc/topics/cac_useresults_junit.html):

```
cypress run --reporter junit
```

However, using a testing monitoring service that requires test reporting results using [**NUnit XML Format**](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Test-Result-XML-Format.html)

Is anyone aware of a solution for either, or both?:

1. Generates Cypress reports in [**NUnit XML Format**](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Test-Result-XML-Format.html)
2. Command-line tool that transforms from [**JUnit XML Format**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.1.1/com.ibm.rsar.analysis.codereview.cobol.doc/topics/cac_useresults_junit.html) to [**NUnit XML Format**](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Test-Result-XML-Format.html)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although originally targeted at Jenkins, this may work for you...

https://github.com/nunit/nunit-transforms/tree/master/nunit3-junit

Answer (score 0):

Found an **XSLT Template** to transform **JUnit XML** reports to **NUnit XML**:

[**junit-to-nunit**](https://github.com/artberri/junit-to-nunit)

Transforms are working using [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/).

Investigating performing transforms using JavaScript, possibly using new **npm module [XSLTjs](https://github.com/Xcential-Corporation/XSLTjs)**.