# What is the simplest way to generate a pickles report out of the test results of behave?

Tags: python, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I am writing behavior tests in python with [behave](https://github.com/behave/behave). I would like to generate a [pickles](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles) report. What is the simplest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There multiple possibilities, each coming with its own advantages and inconvenients.

Pickles supports xUnit, NUnit, and cucumber-json reports, among others. So I need to find a way to get a report from behave in one of those formats. xUnit and NUnit are .NET-specific formats, so they have no relation with python. Behave supports, however, json output. Unfortunately, behave's json output is not the cucumber-json format pickles expects.

### Convert JUnit test reports into NUnit reports through an XSLT transformation

Of course, `behave` supports `JUnit` and it's possible to convert the JUnit test to NUnit through an XSLT transformation. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66443663/4434140), there is a (possibly outdated) XSLT transformation [here](https://github.com/artberri/junit-to-nunit). Such a transformation can be carried out with Apache Ant, which is great, because I am working on TeamCity which comes with a build type of that kind. In Kotlin DSL, this means I could update my build step with something like

```kotlin
steps {

  [whatever script steps or other stuff]

  ant {
    mode = antScript {
      content = """
        <target name="transform" description="Run functional tests">
          <xslt in="${'$'}{PATH_TO_THE_JUNIT_FILE}" out="${'$'}{PATH_TO_THE_NUNIT_FILE}"  style="junit-to-nunit.xsl" />
        </target>
        """.trimIndent()
    }
    targets = "transform"
  }

}
```

The problem with that approach is that I need to install a lot of Java stuff on my development PC if I want to test such a script and I am not very fond of Java stuff. Other than that, there is [this npm package](https://github.com/Xcential-Corporation/XSLTjs) that could help. It has not a lot of stars, but it might work well. To sum up, I am not very comfortable with XSLTs, therefore I don't like this solution.

### Use [behave2cucumber](https://github.com/behalf-oss/behave2cucumber)

The package name sounds really great, and using it seems very easy. So this was a priori my preferred solution. It is as simple as

```bash
pip install behave2cucumber
behave --format=json -o json-report.json /path/to/features
python -m behave2cucumber -i json-report.json -o cucumber-report.json
```

If that worked, I would've been so happy, because essentially everything is available from pypi, sounds really great. However, all my `Background` steps were flagged as `skipped` in my `cucumber-report.json` output, making that solution a no-go, because it doesn't show the right status of my scenarios.

### Write my own custom formatter

Following [this github issue](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/267), I stumbled upon [some explanations](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/267#issuecomment-251746565) and [some code](https://gist.github.com/fredizzimo/b92adf1d4596c0c1da1b05cc9899574b) ([same code here](https://github.com/Xray-App/tutorial-python-behave/blob/main/cucumber_json126.py)). Here are the steps it took me to make it work:

1. copy / paste the [code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fredizzimo/b92adf1d4596c0c1da1b05cc9899574b/raw/5f51c420da623759934e4c336bf9be026b8c773c/cucumber_json_1.2.6.py) into file `venv/Lib/site-packages/behave/formatter/cucumber_json.py`
2. run

```bash
behave --format=behave.formatter.cucumber_json:PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter -o cucumber-report.json /path/to/features
```

And that works like a charm. Because I need this formatter in many projects, my next steps will be to produce a python package that I can install in those projects and reference something like this:

```py
# run_behave.py
import os

from behave.configuration import Configuration
from behave.formatter import _registry
from behave.runner import Runner
from my_formatter_package import PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

_registry.register_as("PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter", PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter)
configuration = Configuration(junit_directory="behave_reports")
configuration.format = ["PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter"]
configuration.stdout_capture = False
configuration.stderr_capture = False
configuration.paths = [os.path.join(here, "features")]
Runner(configuration).run()
```

And that should do the trick. The inconvenient of that approach is that I need to maintain my own formatter. I don't know what new behave versions will change in the json output in the future and how the [cucumber-json schema](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-json-schema/blob/main/schema.json) will evolve with time. Hopefully this formatter will get integrated to `behave`.